# Install RTVS R Host Broker Service

Tags: sql-server, r, visual-studio, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-r

We've tried to setup remote work spaces on a Windows 2012 R2 server to allow R for Visual Studio (RTVS) to connect remotely to that server.

We've following the MS install guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/rtvs/setting-up-remote-r-workspaces however we haven't been able to get the service working.

The install guide mentions v1.0, but this isn't available in github and v1.3 gives different results to those described in the install guide. After running the installer none of the expected services **R Host Broker Service** and **R User Profile Service** were showing under services or task manager, even after a reboot.

Also the install guide references a config file (**Microsoft.R.Host.Broker.Config.json**) where you specify the certificate to be used, this file didn’t exist under the v1.3 file or anywhere on the C drive.

Has anyone managed to get this working?